# How can I use C++ 11 features in Clang?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

How can I use the latest C++ 11 features in Clang? What (sub)set of features is supported?

Comment: I added the [tag:c++11] tag here, this question seems likely to generate enough interest in the future that having the extra visibility to C++11 experts up front seems worth it to me -- but if you guys wish to restrict the tag to strictly _language_ issues, please feel free to remove it -- and I'd be curious in knowing about it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You will need clang 3.3 to use the most relevant feature set from C++ 11. Read [C++ Support in Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) for the complete list of up-to-date supported features. Clang 3.3 is claimed to be C++11 feature complete.

Clang's command line is gcc-compatible so you have to enable C++11 support via the followinf command-line switch

```
-std=c++11
```

There is also a bunch of post-C++11 features (like decltype(auto), member initializers and aggregates) that are supported by Clang 3.3. Use this command line switch to enable them

```
-std=c++1y
```

Comment: Which makes the point that unfortunately this page is not up-to-date... I'll raise this issue on the list :x

Comment: It is, but there is a problem that makes it not update cache... so just Ctrl+R and you'll get it.

Comment: If you are using clang/llvm on Mac, you will also have to add -stdlib=libc++  (besides the -std=c++11 flag) to access most features as they are not available in the old libstdc++. But beware - you will get abi-inconsistencies when passing std-objects to libraries linked with libstdc++ (for example if you use boost that you haven't manually compiled with libc++)

Comment: Is there an option when building clang from source, that can be used to make c++11 enabled by default?

Answer (score 17):

Here is the always up to date list of features supported by clang:

http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

To activate C++11, you have to add -std=c++11 in your clang calls, like for gcc.
If you use an IDE that is clang-aware or gcc-aware, there is a specific project settings option available to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Clang LSP, write your arguments in a file on the same directory called `compile_flags.txt` or `compile_flags.json`