# clang++ 3.1 but no `cxx_lambdas` on Lion Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, xcode4.3, clang++

This is related to [Clang 3.1 and C++11 support status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601545/clang-3-1-and-c11-support-status), but I could not find an answer there and I am being more specific here: `cxx_lambdas` support on clang 3.1 on my exact setup.

I installed Xcode 4.3.3 and the latest command line tools package (June 11, 2012) on OSX Lion 10.7.4. I now have *clang++ version 3.1*:

```
llins@jupara:~/projects/tests/C++11$ clang++ -v
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Based on http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html, I was expecting features `cxx_lambdas` to be available, but this is not what I am getting:

```
llins@jupara:~/projects/tests/C++11$ make
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test_clang_features.cpp -o test_clang_features

llins@jupara:~/projects/tests/C++11$ ./test_clang_features 
FAILED feature tests: 
__has_feature(cxx_constexpr) .................................. FAILED
__has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers) ................... FAILED
__has_feature(cxx_inheriting_constructors) .................... FAILED
__has_feature(cxx_lambdas) .................................... FAILED
__has_feature(cxx_local_type_template_args) ................... FAILED
__has_feature(cxx_unrestricted_unions) ........................ FAILED
__has_feature(cxx_user_literals) .............................. FAILED
```

Here is the the code I ran to get this report:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    cout << "FAILED feature tests: " << endl;

//  testing all features cxx_???? described in (only 3 shown here):
//      http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/tools/clang/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#cxx11

#if !__has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers)
    cout << "__has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers) ................... FAILED" << endl;
#endif
#if !__has_feature(cxx_implicit_moves)
    cout << "__has_feature(cxx_implicit_moves) ............................. FAILED" << endl;
#endif
//... analogous tests ...
#if !__has_feature(cxx_lambdas)
    cout << "__has_feature(cxx_lambdas) .................................... FAILED" << endl;
#endif
}
```

Note that `cxx_lambdas` failed. Here is the complete list of features tested:

```
cxx_access_control_sfinae cxx_alias_templates cxx_alignas
cxx_attributes cxx_auto_type cxx_constexpr cxx_decltype
cxx_default_function_template_args cxx_defaulted_functions
cxx_delegating_constructors cxx_deleted_functions cxx_exceptions
cxx_explicit_conversions cxx_generalized_initializers
cxx_implicit_moves cxx_inheriting_constructors cxx_inline_namespaces
cxx_lambdas cxx_local_type_template_args cxx_noexcept
cxx_nonstatic_member_init cxx_nullptr cxx_override_control
cxx_range_for cxx_raw_string_literals
cxx_reference_qualified_functions cxx_rtti cxx_rvalue_references
cxx_static_assert cxx_strong_enums cxx_trailing_return
cxx_unicode_literals cxx_unrestricted_unions cxx_user_literals
cxx_variadic_templates
```

**Why `cxx_lambdas` is not available in this setup of clang++ 3.1?**

Comment: `Apple clang version 3.1` is not the same as `Clang version 3.1`. Thank Apple for making such a simple thing as versioning difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambada support will be available with Xcode 4.4+
Apple's clang/llvm distribution is customized as ildjarn pointed out...