# Xcode tools on Mac support c++11?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I do most of my coding using Qt in C++ and have noticed that I get x86 architecture not found errors when I enable support for C++11 in my Qt .pro files.

I have the latest Ver of Xcode and have developer tools installed. I realize that OSX uses clang but it still seems that I am still stuck with OSX only supporting earlier versions of gcc.

Is there a reason we can't get these updates from Xcode, and if not I guess I need to install these updates myself?

Comment: You could (compile and) install a recent GCC (e.g. [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) ...) then use `g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -Wall`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use clang with this FLAGS `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` to use C++11 features, another similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408849/how-can-i-use-c-11-features-in-clang)

Comment: I don't enough points to give you an upvote but I did accept your answer, thanks!