# Clang : Failed to find C++11 headers

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I am trying to build all the examples in the Crow library with clang 3.6 and I can see the CC/CXX has been found properly  by using clang 3.6. It uses cmake which I am not quite familiar with.

However it failed to find C++11 headers.

Error is like:

> 'future' file not found

It seems that the libstdc++ is not specified properly, or some people reckon it needs to build the clang libstdc++ myself.

Anyone can shed some light on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you use C++ 11 features with Clang:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408849/how-can-i-use-c-11-features-in-clang

Comment: Clang should offer ABI compatibility with libstdc++ already, so you shouldn't need to build a special version for clang. You might need to link to a specific abi support library (libsupc++ vs. libc++abi), or you may need update libstdc++ to a version that supports C++11, or use libc++ with -stdlib=libc++.

Comment: @CiprianKhlud, actually I did turn it on in cmake:
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++")

Answer (score 0):

So based on the previous comment the issue is that you don't enable the C++ 11 mode in Clang.

As in [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408849/how-can-i-use-c-11-features-in-clang), the issue is simply that you do not say to Clang (or in future for GCC) to look for C++ headers.

"Clang's command line is gcc-compatible so you have to enable C++11 support via the followinf command-line switch"

```
-std=c++11
```

If after this you all you have to do is to write your C++ 11 code. If you use Makefiles you should add to your CXX arguments the command line switch to Clang.

Comment: I actually did turn it on as following:

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++")

My concern is that clang tries to use system default c++ headers/libraries which is not the gcc 4.8 I installed. some people saying that I need to rebuild clang with --with-gcc-toolchain to tell where to find my gcc 4.8. but I am trying to avoid rebuilding clang though.

Comment: Did you try to compile the file in isolation? And use the clang++ (or g++ if you want) just to see if it finds this header? (I would expect to find it)

Comment: it failed to find unordered_map file when I build in this way:
/usr/local/bin/clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ excample.cpp

Comment: So to follow some instructions from googling, I tried to build Clang's libc++abi and libc++ projects, but I ended up with an error:

cc : error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'