# Create a type trait with lookup tables

Tags: c++, enums, type-traits

I'm recently new to using templates as a C++ feature and some of the more recent additions from C++ 11-17.

I'm trying to define a type trait for an enum class, which has some static and constant lookup tables that convert between my enum, and characters:

Enum Class:

```
// DNA nucleotide symbols.
    enum class DNA : uint8_t {
        Gap, A, C, M, G, R, S, V,
        T, W, Y, H, K, D, B, N, Invalid
    };
```

type trait:

```
template<typename T>
    struct conversion_table {};

template<>
    struct conversion_table<DNA> {
        static constexpr DNA from_char[256] = {DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Gap, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::A,
                                               DNA::B, DNA::C, DNA::D,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::G,
                                               DNA::H, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::K, DNA::Invalid, DNA::M,
                                               DNA::N, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::R, DNA::S,
                                               DNA::T, DNA::Invalid, DNA::V,
                                               DNA::W, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Y,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::A, DNA::B,
                                               DNA::C, DNA::D, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::G, DNA::H,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::K,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::M, DNA::N,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::R, DNA::S, DNA::T,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::V, DNA::W,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Y, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid, DNA::Invalid,
                                               DNA::Invalid};

        static constexpr char to_char[16] = {'-', 'A', 'C', 'M', 'G', 'R', 'S', 'V', 'T', 'W',
                                             'Y', 'H', 'K', 'D', 'B', 'N'};
    };
```

However as far as I know static makes it defined once for all instances of the struct, and constexpr means the tables should be evaluated at compile time.

However, if I use this in a main function like so:

```
#import "../biosymbols.h"

int main(){

    auto a = biosymbols::conversion_table<biosymbols::DNA>::from_char['A'];

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error during compilation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "biosymbols::conversion_table<biosymbols::DNA>::from_char", referenced from:
      _main in biosymbols_checks.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not sure why though, as this is similar to examples of creating type traits on the web. Can anyone point me to what I need to be doing to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Seem to work on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/28lKCj7o2E0Dh6mZ)

Comment: Also, that's not a compilation error, it's a linking error.

Comment: That's strange, I have it in it's own .h file I #include, which shouldn't make any difference, but when I make CLion build it, it gives me the linker error.

Comment: Make sure to [enable C++11 support for Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10408912/7571258).